# Pub/sub with Redis: how to make a subscription expire

Tags: java, redis, vert.x

We re using redis pub/sub in a java framework (vertx) to track some rest calls.

In order not to overload the Redis, I am unsubscribing from a channel after 30 seconds as follows:

```
private void subscribe(Message<String> message) {

    String msgId = message.body();
    redisClient.subscribe(msgId, result -> {
        if (!result.succeeded()) {
            log.warn("subscribe failed msgId={}", msgId, result.cause());
            message.fail(500, String.format("retrieve conversation %s failure", msgId));
            return;
        }

        log.info("subscribed for message id :{}", msgId);
        message.reply("OK");

        //unsubscribe after 30 seconds.
        vertx.setTimer(30000, r -> {
            redisClient.unsubscribe(Collections.singletonList(msgId), r2 -> {
                if(!r2.succeeded()){
                    log.warn("unsubscribe failed msgId={}", msgId, r2.cause());
                }
            });

        });
    });
}
```

I wonder if there is a way in redis to rollback a subscription after a delay or alike..

Any ideas for improvement are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

No there isn't.

According to the docs: https://redis.io/commands/subscribe

You can only specify the channels you want to listen to. You either disconnect or issue the `UNSUBSCRIBE` command.